# Locky ransomware removal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, malware

My internet provider informed me that my computer is infected with Locky Ransomware. I have Linux Ubuntu. How to remove virus or scan system?

Comment: Odd for Locky Ransomware, which uses a Excel/Word macro (Visual Basic Script) vector to infect Linux.  https://blog.avast.com/a-closer-look-at-the-locky-ransomware

Comment: I received information from my internet provider that they detected locky on my computer. Maybe this is false alarm. However I want to check this due to possible losses associated with this virus/trojan

Comment: Pardon, _they_ detected something on _your_ computer? Really? Do they have remote administration access to your computer?

Comment: They informed me that they detected a trial of locky ransomware attack on my computer from some servers or something like that. sorry for imprecise description, I am not a computer scientist.

Comment: Think carefully. Was it really your internet provider, or someone claiming to be your internet provider? What evidence did _they give you_ that leads you to believe they are who they claim to be?

Comment: website is certified and I made a phone to them personally 5 minutes ago to confirm this issue.

Comment: Please don't pay them $2000 over a gift card. Or give them any money at all to fix "the ransomware"

Comment: Read once again my message above. If you dont have nothing valuable to say,better dont say anything at all.

Comment: and if you know that possibilities of ubuntu infection by such trojan is 0, then simply tell me this instead of  arrogant,worthless jokes. because for person who is not involved in computer science and cybersecurity, things like that are not obvious.

Comment: What joke? Advising users to not give money to a extremely suspicious situation is sound advice. Not a computer scientist here either.

Comment: What Francesc wrote was not arrogant, not worthless, and not a joke.  It was well-meant and likely relevant advice, politely put.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a false premise (a telephone scam) that is not relevant to Unix or Linux.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the website address they gave you to confirm that they are legitimate? Regarding the phone number that they gave you to call. Is this your Internet Provider's public number, and if not, how do you know that you are really phoning them and not a fraudster?

Comment: I totally agree with Wildcard. Sorry to all for unnecessary mess and loss of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

False claims that your computer has been infected by malware and that you should install some particular software to fix it are common [scams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scam). They usually pretend to come from someone that many people trust on matters of computer security, such as Microsoft or your service provider. The scam is that they are in fact trying to persuade you to install *their* malware.

There are a few malware that can be detected over the network, through their network traffic, but mostly you would need local access to your machine. Ransomware in particular can't be detected over the network. And even if your ISP did need to contact you about something (e.g. your computer is involved in a botnet), they'd use the contact address they have for you (e.g. email coming from them), they wouldn't inject content in a web page.

**Never install something that someone pretending to be from your ISP/Microsoft/… wants you to install**. If by “website is certified” you mean that it shows a green padlock icon in your browser, that only means that they paid a few dollars and that your browser really is connected to the scammer's site. HTTPS only guarantees that the site that your browser is talking to is the site it pretends to be (i.e. the correct domain name), it doesn't mean that the site that it's talking to is trustworthy. Having a phone likewise guarantees nothing beyond the fact that the scammers are paying someone (likely in a country with low wages) to answer the phone.

When you visit a website, your browser sends some basic information about your computer, including the operating system that you're using. The website also knows your [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) and it can look up which ISP this address belongs to as well as your approximate geographical location through [geolocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation) services. Scammers take advantage of this to pretend that they actually know something about you. It's a classic thing with confidence tricksters to appear more informed that they really are by using clues that they hope you won't think of. In your case pretending that you have a *Windows* malware on your *Linux* machine is clearly wrong, but scammers are looking for the most gullible victims, they don't mind that most people who see the ad will ignore it as an obvious scam.

Such scams are often shown through ads. If the scam appears in an unrelated web page and that web page has a way to report fraudulent ads, do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan your computer with ClamAV. It needs to get installed, but it should be present in the main repository.

I'm not sure if the virus base contains Locky Ransomware, but anyhow, make sure to update the signatures before you scan.